# How to update the InnoSetup Wizard GUI status text from PascalScript code

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I execute a lot of custom actions in my InnoSetup script in the CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall) PascalScripting event handler. As these actions take some time to finish, I'd like to update the InnoSetup Wizard GUI status text and tell the user what is going on behind the scenes. Something similar that is possible in the [Run] section using the "StatusMsg" parameter. I know that I could use the TOutputProgressWizardPage/CreateOutputProgressPage(), and I did in a previous project, but it's a bit too much overkill to my liking...

Is there a simpler possibility to update the InnoSetup Wizard GUI status text from PascalScripting code with the same effect as the StatusMsg parameter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this from your CurStepChanged handler:

```
WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'status update';
```