# How to update the InnoSetup Wizard GUI status text from PascalScript code during uninstall

Tags: installation, inno-setup

During installation, it's possible to update the InnoSetup wizard status text from inside the PascalScript event handler "CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)" with the following code ([How to update the InnoSetup Wizard GUI status text from PascalScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514107)):

```
WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'status update';
```

This does not work for uninstall. Accessing this property from inside "CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)" fails with the following error:

```
"Runtime Error: Line 526: Exception: Internal Error: An attempt was made to access WizardForm before it has been created."
```

Any idea how the InnoSetup wizard status text can be changed during uninstall? Maybe "usUninstall" is too early? But the label is already there and visible in the uninstaller's GUI...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'status update';
```