# How to set the status message in [Code] Section of Inno install script?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation

I know that  `StatusMsg`can only be used in the [Run] selection.
I want to use the same in the `[Code]` Selection, 
Please Help me to solve this,

Thanks in advance, Regards Samuel J

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the InnoSetup Wizard GUI status text from PascalScript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514107/how-to-update-the-innosetup-wizard-gui-status-text-from-pascalscript-code)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the status label contents at runtime using:

```
WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Intalling WibbleTech Widget'
```

See the [Support classes reference](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm) for the full list of controls and properties you can change.

Comment: If you want to do this in the `PrepareToInstall` function, it's a bit different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23633694/2534880